# how to write unit test for this case

Tags: java, unit-testing

I need to write a unit test for this method, it reads a list and then build this list to a csv file, for this is my first time to write unit test like this, is there anything I need to notice like which stuff I need to test?
which thing I need to verify?

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "report1",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void report1Builder(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    List<InventoryLevelViewRecordMock> mockQueryResponse = this.InsertMockData();

    StringBuilder csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    //build header
    csvBuilder.append("SKU,Count");

    for (int i =0; i< mockQueryResponse.size(); i++) {
        csvBuilder.append("\n")
                .append(getCsvString(mockQueryResponse.get(i)));
    }

    response.setContentType("text/csv");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename= live-report1.csv");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");

    try {
        response.getOutputStream().write(csvBuilder.toString().getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getCsvString(InventoryLevelViewRecordMock data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(data.SKU);
    sb.append(",");
    sb.append(data.INVENTORY_COUNT);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there anything I need to notice like which stuff I need to test? which thing I need to verify?

- You verify the *observable behavior* of your code under test.
  this is
  1 return values
  2 interaction with dependencies
  3 error conditions
- Each test verifies exactly one assuption.

Comment: for this method there is no return value, what is 3 error conditions? I only see one